# JNI Passing struct argument

Tags: java, c, struct, java-native-interface

I want to know how will I write My C code to map the Java Object Variables to a Struct 
MY java class is calling a native method written in C ,below is my  code.

JavaCode:

```
public class JNIWrapper {

static{
    System.loadLibrary("JNIDemo");
}

public native int packet_mining_start(pax_store_mining_query_param_s   packet_mining_params);
}
```

My class pax_store_mining_query_param_s :

```
public class pax_store_mining_query_param_s {
String query_id;                        // A unique number, if applicable.
                        // A unique number, if applicable.
String flow_id;                     
String time_start;
String time_end;
}
```

Header Files :
1)sam_api:

```
    /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
    #include <jni.h>
   /* Header for class demo_JNIWrapper */

   #ifndef _Included_demo_JNIWrapper
   #define _Included_demo_JNIWrapper
   #include "pax_store_mining.h"//Contains my C structures 
   #ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
   #endif
   JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_demo_JNIWrapper_packet_1mining_1start
     (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject);

   }
```

3)My Second Header File containing The struct :

```
     #ifndef PAX_STORE_QUERY_H
#define PAX_STORE_QUERY_H

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
struct pax_store_mining_query_param_s {
    uint32_t query_id;                      // A unique number, if applicable.
    uint64_t flow_id;                       
    uint64_t time_start;
    uint64_t time_end;
};
```

4)Below is my C code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "demo_JNIWrapper.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_demo_JNIWrapper_packet_1mining_1start
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj, jobject packet_mining_params){

return 0;

}
```

I want to map this packet_mining_params struct from my java object which has the same name and params as this. Will this be automatically mapped?

Comment: Your java and C structs will not be automatically mapped. Even if jni could do this, your class and structs aren't compatible anyway. You have String members in your Java class and integral types in your C struct. Also, you shouldn't edit the JNI generated header file. It says so right there in the comments.

Comment: You might try using JNI through SWIG or JNA (two very different approaches that use JNI internally).